# mock patch fails for some reason

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to patch an API for unit testing purposes. I have a class like this:

```
# project/lib/twilioclient.py
from os import environ
from django.conf import settings
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

    def __init__(self):
        return super(Client, self).__init__(
            settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
        )

client = Client()
```

and this method:

```
# project/apps/phone/models.py
from project.lib.twilioclient import Client
# snip imports

class ClientCall(models.Model):
    'call from Twilio'
    # snip model definition

    def dequeue(self, url, method='GET'):
        '''"dequeue" this call (take off hold)'''
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
        Client().calls.route(
            sid=self.sid,
            method=method,
            url=urljoin('http://' + site.domain, url)
        )
```

and then the following test:

```
# project/apps/phone/tests/models_tests.py
class ClientCallTests(BaseTest):
    @patch('project.apps.phone.models.Client', autospec=True)
    def test_dequeued(self, mock_client):
        cc = ClientCall()
        cc.dequeue('test', 'TEST')

        mock_client.calls.route.assert_called_with(
            sid=cc.sid,
            method='TEST',
            url='http://example.com/test',
        )
```

When I run the test, it fails because the real client is called instead of the mock client.

Looks like it should work to me, and I've been able to make this type of thing work before. I've tried the usual suspects (removing `*.pyc`) and things don't seem to be changing. Is there a new behavior here that I'm missing somehow?

Comment: is there any calls at all? or there is no calls...

Comment: there's definitely a call - to what? The test calls `ClientCall.dequeue`, which instantiates `Client`. `Client` oughta be a Mock there, but it isn't.

Comment: or check `mock_client.mock_calls`

Comment: if I fail in dequeue (`assert False`) and print out "Client" first, I get a `twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient`. Is that what you mean by "debug"?

Comment: I mean use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: I can there (but through nose.) That doesn't help me much, however, as the mock object is not in scope. Elvis has left the building!